# Implementing an SQLite Database in Android App

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application allows the user to create a text message and specify a time and date for when they would like it to be sent. I'm having some issues though. Due to the nature of Pending Intents I'm not able to create a new one for each message. Thus if a user submits a new text to be sent before the pending intent is executed it overwrites the previous message. So as it stands I can't have more than one message queued up to send.

My solution to this was to maintain an SQLite database with the various message details and simply update the pending intent with whichever message comes next in the database. This also has the added benefit of making implementation of displaying a list of current messages to be sent and editing messages to be sent a lot simpler.

The issue is I don't think I'm setting up the database properly. When I run in debug mode it doesn't seem to be entering my database helper class (MessagesHelper) and instantiating the database variable. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and have been following the android SQLite dev guide. Would appreciate any help/tips you can give me.

**Table Contract Class**

```
public class Messages {
    private Messages(){}

    public static abstract class Texts implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "texts";
        public static final String DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER = "stime DESC";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_RECIPIENT = "recipient";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE = "message";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SEND_TIME = "stime";
        public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.rastelliJ.deferredSMS";
    }
}
```

**DB Helper Class**

```
public class MessagesHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String TAG = "MessagesHelper";
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
                                    "CREATE TABLE " + Messages.Texts.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                                    Messages.Texts._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                                    Messages.Texts.COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                                    Messages.Texts.COLUMN_NAME_RECIPIENT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                                    Messages.Texts.COLUMN_NAME_SEND_TIME + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Messages.Texts.TABLE_NAME;

    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Messages.db";

    MessagesHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
    }
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private CustomDateTimePicker customDT;
private MessagesHelper mDbHelper;
private EditText phoneName, messageText;
private String phoneNum, alarmtime;
private TextView alarmText;
private Button sendButt;
private int pickerHour = 0, 
            pickerMin = 0, 
            pickerYear = 0, 
            pickerMonth = 0, 
            pickerDay = 0;

private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Set up the custom Date Time Picker
    customDT = new CustomDateTimePicker(this, new  CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {
            public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                String AM_PM) { 
                    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
                    pickerYear = year;
                    pickerMonth = monthNumber;
                    pickerDay = date;
                    pickerHour = hour24;
                    pickerMin = min;
                    alarmtime = weekDayFullName + ", " + monthFullName + " " + date + ", " + year + " " + hour12 + ":" + pickerMin + " " + AM_PM;
                    alarmText.setText("Send Date: " + alarmtime);
                }

            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    customDT.set24HourFormat(false);
    customDT.setDate(Calendar.getInstance());
    findViewById(R.id.startTimeSetDialog).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                customDT.showDialog();
            }
        });

    // Setup global variables
    phoneName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNo);
    messageText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    sendButt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    alarmText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmPrompt);

    //Create/Find DB
    mDbHelper = new MessagesHelper(this);

    // Start Contact finder
    phoneName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
        }
    });

    // "Send" the message
    sendButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Make sure the fields are filled
            if (phoneName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            if (messageText.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            //Create a calendar variable that equates to the desired time to be sent
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, pickerYear);
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, pickerMonth);
            cal.set(Calendar.DATE, pickerDay);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, pickerHour);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, pickerMin);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            //Set up the pending intent and assign put it in the alarm manger
            //will change this process once db is set up proper
            Intent sIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendTService.class);
            sIntent.putExtra("phoneNo", phoneNum.toString());
            sIntent.putExtra("msgTxt", messageText.getText().toString());
            PendingIntent psIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this,0, sIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), psIntent);

            //Add the latest message to the db
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Messages.Texts.COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE, messageText.getText().toString());
            values.put(Messages.Texts.COLUMN_NAME_RECIPIENT, phoneNum.toString());
            values.put(Messages.Texts.COLUMN_NAME_SEND_TIME, cal.toString());
            db.insert(Messages.Texts.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            //Clear all the fields and let the user know what's going on
            phoneName.setText("");
            messageText.setText("");
            alarmText.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Message will be sent on " + alarmtime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

//Associated with the Contact picker getting it's results
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
        switch (requestCode) {  
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;  
                String phoneNumber = "";
                List<String> allNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                int phoneIdx = 0;
                try {  
                    Uri result = data.getData();  
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();  
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);  
                    phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                    {
                        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
                        {
                            phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                            allNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
                            cursor.moveToNext();
                        }
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        //no results actions
                    }  
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {  
                   //error actions
                } 
                finally 
                {  
                    if (cursor != null) cursor.close();

                    final CharSequence[] items = allNumbers.toArray(new String[allNumbers.size()]);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Choose a number");
                    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) 
                        {
                            phoneNum = items[item].toString();
                            phoneNum = phoneNum.replace("-", "");
                            phoneName.setText(phoneNum);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    if(allNumbers.size() > 1)
                    {
                        alert.show();
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        phoneNum = phoneNumber.toString();
                        phoneNum = phoneNum.replace("-", "");
                        phoneName.setText(phoneNum);
                    }

                    if (phoneNumber.length() == 0) 
                    {  
                        //no numbers found actions  
                    }  
                }  
                break;  
            }  
        } 
    else 
    {
       //activity result error actions
    }  
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess: your `SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES` statement is missing the semicolon at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement. In Google's Notepad example and in all of my databases I've always included the semicolon and never had a problem.